# Images issue in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

When I tried to import an image from vuforia target manager, it appears in unity3D as a white plane, whatever the image is, especially if it is a black image.
how can I solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didn't do it right in one of these steps:

1. Verify your image target in the site: (show features)
2. Download as Unity package
3. In Unity, import package…
4. Drag and drop a prefab for AR Camera
5. Check the box for your Image Target to make sure it is enabled
6. Drag and drop a prefab for Image target
7. Set the DB and your image target in the Image Target properties
8. You have to see the texture of your image target in the prefab. (Not a white plane)

Comment: the problem was that the desired target was not augmentable

Answer (score 2):

1 ) Go to Project > Editor > QCAR > ImageTargetTextures > DataBaseName   in Project Window Assets Folder.
 2) Click on ImageNmae_scaled
 3) In inspector window Set : 
                3.1)  Texture Type to : Default
                3.2) Texture shape to : 2D 
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miX0W.jpg) 
4) Hit Apply
 5) Click on ImageTarget in Hierarchy View and in inspector select Database and your Image target
 6) You Are Done !

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks !!
Can you also share the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem in 5.5.1 Unity for me. Following those steps doesn't work for me, but if I go to the imported image textures I can change the texture type to light map or sprite and they will show the actual image. Not sure why that is required now, but I can't seem to figure out any other way. The application works perfect with the panels being white, but it's hard to properly position my prefab models on it. Changing the texture types so I can view the image doesn't seem to mess with anything either so that is one solution if anyone is having this problem still.

Answer (score 0):

when you have more problems, you can also try not to use object recongition. You can try to use cloud recognition. Vuforia allow us to create a cloud recognition as a target database.
It may solve your problem.