# vuforia image target is white (not showing my image target)

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

When i import an image from Vuforia Target Manager into my Unity3d I get a white plane instead of the image i had uploaded.

My Vuforia Ver: 6.1.17
My Unity3d Ver: 5.5.0f3 Personal

I had followed the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719847/images-issue-in-vuforia)

but it still didnt work. 
Is there any issue with the vuforia website as the image that it gave is white, when viewed in Unity3d IDE.

[Image which is seen in unity3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CWaD.png)

[Image uploaded to Vuforia Target Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgcly.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Assets>Editor>QCAR>ImageTargetTextures>(YourDB).
Select Image> Click on the settings icon in the Inspector pane......
click on Reset

[Click here for more info](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/image-target-textures-not-show-upwhite-texture-shown-scene-unity3d)

Hope it works....

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue recently after upgrading unity 5.2.2 to 5.5.1
initially, I thought it's Vuforia software bug and replaced it with an earlier version of Vuforia but no use. But the app will track the image
The problem is with unity 5.5 version. I downgraded to 5.2.2 for some other reasons and now it's showing the target image as erlier

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to downgrade or make any software changes inside Unity.

I came across the same issue, and got it solved in a simple manner.
What I did was:

Changed the type of texture of the image to Sprite (2D and UI).
The file path for the following will be :

1. *Assets > Editor > QAR > 'DATABASE_NAME' > 'TARGET_FILE_NAME'*
2. Change the texture type to Sprtie (2D and UI)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the latest version of Unity 2018.3.11 and Vuforia 7.x. I don't think it's a bug. It might just be a very poor design on there part. Not to mention the fact that their documentation is very limited when it comes to cloud reco!

I guess the debug process as far as scaling will just be trial and error.